# Python 2d interpolation of 3d array

Tags: python, 2d, interpolation

I have a global precipitation data with dimensions (time=410,lat=72,lon=144). I wish to interpolate lat to 180 and lon to 360 (i.e., downscale the data from 2.5 degrees to 1 degree).

In Matlab I used to do:

```
%LAT,LON,XI,YI are old and new meshgridded lat-lons
for t = 1:size(precip,1)
    newPrecip(t,:,:)=interp2(LON,LAT,squeeze(precip(t,:,:)),XI,YI);
end
```

In python I have tried `interp2d`, `map_coordinates`, and `interp` (basemap) functions, but without success.

Here's my code with `map_coordinates`, which got me closest to getting a result

```
new_indicies = np.mgrid[0:410, -89.5:89.5:180J, -179.5:179.5:360J]
newPrecip = ndimage.map_coordinates(precip, new_indicies, order=1)
```

The new data does have the dimensions I want (410,180,360), but it doesn't actually interpolate, instead it just fills the newly added grids (around the original data) with 0 values.

I am new to python, and I would appreciate any help in getting a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the interpolation routine that comes with [Basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/).

```
import mpl_toolkits.basemap as mp
Zg = mp.interp(dataIN,lonIN,latIN,lonOUT,latOUT,
               checkbounds=False, masked=False, order=1)
```

Here, lonIN and latIN are 1D longitude-latitude of the original grid (assuming regular grid), dataIn is 2D array of the original data, lonOUT and latOUT are 2D grid you want to interpolate to, while Zg is the output on the new grid. The output grid can be created using:

```
x=np.arange(-180,180,1)
y=np.arange(-90,90,1)
lonOUT,latOUT=np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

Hope this helps. Cheers, Trond

Comment: ,thanks for your answer. I had tried it but put dataIN,latIN,lonIN..) instead of (dataIN,LonIN,LatIN..). Silly Me. I will put my successful code for reference for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into `scipy.interpolate`. Looks like [griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata) might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Trond, I realized what I was doing wrong. Here's the final code that works for me. Hope it serves as reference to others. This is the first time I've posted at Stackoverflow and am very happy that my query got answered quickly and correctly!

```
#this code assumes a input data 'precip' of dimensions (410,72,144)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import interp

LAT=np.arange(-89.5,90.5,1)
LON=np.arange(-179.5,180.5,1)
LON,LAT=np.meshgrid(LON,LAT)
lat=np.arange(-88.75,91.25,2.5)
lon=np.arange(-178.75,181.25,2.5)

newPrecip=np.zeros((410,180,360), dtype='float')
for i in range(410):
    newPrecip[i,:,:]=interp(np.squeeze(precip[i,:,:]),lon,lat,LON,LAT,order=1)

plt.figure(1)
plt.pcolor(lon,lat,precip.mean(axis=0))
plt.figure(2)
plt.pcolor(LON,LAT,newPrecip.mean(axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the PyKrige Library if you want an Ordinary Kriging interpolation!

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation as to how that library can help the OP, with snippets of code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer